# Store intime/outtime according to roll no.s in a file

Tags: c++, file

I have been asked to write a program that asks the rollno from user to let the student go inside first and then keep that InTime fixed and only change the  outTime by asking the rollno of the student within a given range any number of times the user wishes to send them out. Here is the code i wrote:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<fstream.h>
#include<time.h>
int main()
{
char *intime[10],*outtime[10],d='\0';
int rollno[10]={10,4,1,5,6,2,3,7,9,8},i,c;
time_t obj;
time(&obj);
struct tm* t;
t=localtime(&obj);

ofstream f;

f.open("fit.txt");

cout<<"Enter your roll no to go in.\n";

cin>>c;


intime[c]=asctime(t);
     cout<<"Enter your roll no to go out.\n";

cin>>c;
while(c>=1 && c<=10)
{



     outtime[c]=asctime(t);
 }

f<<rollno[c]<<" "<<intime[c]<<" "<<outtime[c]<<endl;


 f.close();
 ifstream t1;
 t1.open("fit.txt");
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{

cout<<" "<<rollno[i]<<" "<<intime[i]<<" "<<outtime[i]<<endl;  }

t1.close();
return 0;
}
```

Problem is that since i am unable to update intime and outtime apart from those that are requested for, iam getting garbage value.. help needed.

**Update:** here is the final code that i have come up with ,it's not giving any garbage values and is giving different values of intime and outtime, please feel free to suggest further improvements on this

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<fstream.h>
#include<time.h>
int main()
{

int i,j;char *intime[10],*outtime[10],it[10],ot[10];

for(i =1;i<=10;i++)
{
 intime[i]="0";
 outtime[i]="0";
}
int rollno[10]={10,4,1,5,6,2,3,7,9,8},c;
time_t obj,obj1;
time(&obj);

struct tm* t;
struct tm* u;

t=gmtime(&obj);


ofstream f;

f.open("fit.txt");

cout<<"Enter your roll no to go in.\n";

cin>>c;

for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
if(rollno[i]==c)

{strftime(it,10,"%I:%M:%S",t);
intime[i]=it;}


 cout<<"Enter your roll no to go out.\n";

cin>>c;
time(&obj);

u=gmtime(&obj);

 for(j=1;j<=10;j++)
 if(rollno[j]==c)
 {
 if(intime[j]!="0")

   { strftime(ot,10,"%I:%M:%S",u);
    outtime[j]=ot;}
  }




 f.close();
 ifstream t1;
 t1.open("fit.txt");

for(i=1;i<=10;i++)

cout<<" "<<rollno[i]<<" "<<intime[i]<<" "<<outtime[i]<<endl;


t1.close();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the `intime` and `outime` arrays right after you create them. Somethine like

```
std::memset(intime, 0, sizeof(intime));
```

Should work for you.

You also have a problem with your use of the `asctime` function. It returns the address of a static string which will get overwritten after each call to `asctime`. You'll need to allocate storage yourself and copy the returned string.

Comment: I tried using memset but it was still giving me garbage values, but your idea about initializing the values right after creating them worked for me i used a for loop  
for(i =1;i<=10;i++)
{
intime[i]=&d;
outtime[i]=&d;
}
this is giving the output without the garbage values .

Comment: There is still the problem of asctime though, im getting the same intime and outtime in the output, i tried using 2 char pointer variables ,and assigned the values returned by asctime to them and then assigned those variable to intime[i] and outtime[i] but im still getting same intime and outtime.

Comment: @Vibhu That's what I said. You need to do a strcpy on the value returned from asctime into your own storage area. asctime just returns a pointer to the same location in memory. Each time you call it, the data in that location is overwritten.